# Spring MockMvc don't expect content

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test

I am trying to test a thymeleaf template that returns content based on the user's spring security role.

I am looking to check that some content does not exist

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

...

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/index"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().string(containsString("This content should be shown.")))
    .andExpect(content().string(XXXXXXX("This content should not be shown")));
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Solution is to use hamcrests CoreMatchers.not(....) method:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(roles = "USER")
public void loginWithRoleUserThenExpectUserSpecificContent() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/index"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("This content is only shown to users.")))
            .andExpect(content().string(doesNotContainString("This content is only shown to administrators.")));
}

private Matcher<String> doesNotContainString(String s) {
    return CoreMatchers.not(containsString(s));
}
```